# Magento how to remove payment option when a specific shipping method is selected

Tags: php, magento

How can I remove a specific payment option when a specific shipping method is checked?

An example would be:
If i select the "Free International Shipping" the "Cash" paymend option must be removed or inactive.

Comment: @KeyurShah i get this error Mage registry key "_singleton/dm_pay/observer" already exists

Comment: can you please put your code here ?

Comment: @KeyurShah i get that error when i do what you suggested, but when i make the tags <global> it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do using `observer`. First of all you have to create one module(I'm assuming you already know how to create module)

In your `config.xml` from `app>code>your_codepol>Namespace>module>etc>config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>YOUR_CLASS_observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

and create your observer and write this code in your `observer.php`

```
public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $event           = $observer->getEvent();
    $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
    $result          = $event->getResult(); 
$quote  = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
   if($shippingMethod=="Free International Shipping"){
        if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){ // to hide this method
            $result->isAvailable = false; // false means payment method is disable
        }
}
```

}

Where `cashondelivery` is payment method name. You can write any payment name like

1. ccsave(Credit Card (saved))
2. checkmo(Check / Money order)
3. purchaseorder(Purchase Order)
4. banktransfer(Bank Transfer Payment)
5. cashondelivery(Cash On Delivery)
   etc..

Let me know if you have any query